# Why am I failing to connect this simple kitchen sink pipe?

Tags: plumbing, sink, drain, kitchen-sink

Hi all I'm having trouble reconnecting this L shaped pipe to the main pipes under the sink. No matter how I arrange or push or connect the slip nuts, they seemed to get jammed by the washer/band around the pipe chokes. And thus the pipes leak.

There are some washer/band things which I believe go inside the slip nuts, example:
[image]

But when I do this I cannot screw the slip nut all the way to the sink hole above, example:
[image]

The best I can do is above, with the band being below the slip nut which I'm sure is not how it is meant to be.
[image]

How do I connect the pipe correctly so it fits to the sink and the other pipes that go through the main drain? Is there some technique I'm not doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid cross-threading, spin it backwards until you feel it drop into another thread; this is where and when it's lined up. First attach it to the sink and then fight with other connection, leaving everything lose until it's all fitted together. For the fitting you have, turn this picture up-side down: (make sure the grommet is properly orientated)

[image]

> The bottom of the drain spout always seals to the drain plumbing using one of these clever conical, or wedge type of gaskets. The nut on top pushes the wedge into the drain pipe, which compresses it and cause it to perfectly seal between the drain plumbing and the spout from the sink. -[woodgears.ca](https://woodgears.ca/sink/replace.html)

Plumbing is always a can of worms; you'll find new fittings much easier to work with, and the reusing of old grommets to be less than ideal. While you're at it, replace it with a sanitary elbow like it should be. Flexible lines should be avoided if at all possible, but they sure make for an easy install.

Comment: your advice worked, I attached to sink first and started to screw the slip nut which worked perfectly. Thanks for your help and quick answer.

Answer (score 1):

In this case the gasket (not band) is supposed to go above the slipnut, it does not matter how much the slipnut is actually tightened on though. It may not go up fully and if it does then the band is way overworn and needs to be replaced. Try putting the gasket back in front/above the slipnut and tightening it! If this holds the water and it doesn't leak then your good to go, if not then the rubber gasket may need to be replaced, that is if you can find one. I would recommend replacing it all as it is outdated anyways.